# typedef a function interface (not function pointer)

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

If I typedef like this:

```
typedef int (read_proc_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
                          int count, int *eof, void *data);
```

as defined [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.0.82/include/linux/proc%5ffs.h#L46)

What is this technique called?

If I typedef this way, which means I create a type `read_proc_t`; later, I create my own version of `read-proc-t`, which is `my_read_proc` and I have a struct like this:

```
struct test {
    read_proc_t read_proc;
} 

struct test t;
```

I can do something like this:

```
t.read_proc_t = my_read_proc;
```

Is this correct? Normally, if I typedef `read_proc_t` as a function pointer:

```
typedef int (*read_proc_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
                          int count, int *eof, void *data);
```

I would have to assign `my_read_proc` function address to the function pointer, like this:

```
(*t.read_proc_t) = &my_read_proc;
```

In which circumstance do I choose one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case the type `read_proc_t` does not get an implicit pointer semantic, while in the second case it becomes a pointer type.

The difference between the two is that the variables of the first type cannot be created in most contexts. For example, it is illegal to define the `struct` like this:

```
struct test {
    // This causes an error in C99:
    // field ‘read_proc’ declared as a function
    read_proc_t read_proc;
};
```

You need an asterisk to make it valid:

```
struct test {
    read_proc_t *read_proc;
};
```

However, `read_proc_t` can be used to declare function parameters:

```
void read_something(read_proc_t rd_proc) {
    rd_proc(...); // Invoke the function
}
```

There is a certain degree of interchangeability between `read_proc_t` and `read_proc_t*`: for example, you can call the above function like this:

```
read_proc_t *rd = my_read_01;
read_something(rd); // <<== read_proc_t* is passed to read_proc_t
```

In general, you should prefer the first declaration to keep the function pointer semantic explicit, because it is better for readability. If you use the second declaration (with an asterisk) you should name the type in a way that tells the reader that it is a pointer, for example, like this:

```
typedef int (*read_proc_ptr_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
                      int count, int *eof, void *data);
```

Answer (score 3):

It has to be a pointer. So if you typedef it like this:

```
typedef int (read_proc_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
                          int count, int *eof, void *data);
```

You use it like this

```
read_proc_t *read_proc = my_read_proc;
```

And if you typedef it like this:

```
typedef int (*read_proc_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
                           int count, int *eof, void *data);
```

You use it like this

```
read_proc_t read_proc = my_read_proc;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef int (read_proc_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
                      int count, int *eof, void *data);
```

This will define `read_proc_t` as a function type, you could define a pointer to it, such as `read_proc_t *read_proc`, but you cannot define a variable of this type. You `struct test` would not work.

Answer (score 3):

In all absolutely all cases you should prefer to use

```
typedef int (read_proc_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
                          int count, int *eof, void *data);
```

and not

```
typedef int (*read_proc_t)(char *page, char **start, off_t off,
                          int count, int *eof, void *data);
```

because the second case hides that the type is a pointer, and this is bad. The first one defines a type that is a function. You cannot have variables of type function in C, but function pointers are fine. So your code should be:

```
struct test {
    read_proc_t *read_proc;
}
```

e.g. `read_proc` is a pointer to a function of type `read_proc_t`.
Notice here that the code clearly expresses what is doing on. With the seconds approach you get `read_proc_t read_proc` which totally hides the pointer aspect.